# Are there any places that serve Korean food in Doi Mai or Mangalia in Romania?

Tags: food-and-drink, south-korea, restaurants, romania, black-sea

Those who've never been here before might not expect it, but there's something of a Korean presence on the Black Sea Coast within 10km of the Bulgarian border.

The main entity is [Daewoo Mangalia Heavy Industries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daewoo_Mangalia_Heavy_Industries). Basically one of Korea's biggest corporations is has a huge shipyard here with Korean equipment, where new ships are built, and I guess ships come for upgrades and repairs too. I took a photo of a Korean ship there this morning which I'll add soon.

Sometimes last summer when I was staying at the next beach south, Vama Veche, I saw a couple of out-of-place middle-aged Asian guys. Now I know they must've been connected in some way to the Daweoo shipyard up the coast.

Now where there's expats there's generally expat food. What I want to know is if there is a restaurant, eatery, canteen, etc in [Doi Mai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Mai) or [Mangalia](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mangalia) just to cater to these far-from-home Korean businessmen and sailors. Because I bet I miss the amazing Korean cuisine almost as much as those guys and I want some too!

**Can I get Korean food around Mangalia, Romania?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the InterWebs there are only two Korean restaurants in Romania, both in Bucharest
([Dami](http://www.restograf.ro/restaurant-coreean-dami-bucuresti/) and [Korea-house](http://www.restograf.ro/restaurant-coreean-korea-house-bucuresti/)), however where-ever there is a good number of Korean tourists or workers, there is usually also a Korean restaurant.

Looking at the [web site](http://www.dmhi.ct.ro) of Daewoo Mangalia Heavy Industries. all the managers listed there have Romanian names, the president and CEO is Korean, but it seems he is based in Korea. So we can assume there are not many Koreans working at the site, and therefore there is no place to get Korean food.

There are a few Chinese places up the coast in Constanta.

Comment: Well researched. I think you're right.

Comment: Genuine Korean restaurants are extremely scarce in Europe. You can find some in major cities. I am really surprised to see that there are two such restaurants in Bucharest. But why not. At least the second one looks a bit authentic.